# Power Query / Power Pivot - Joining two tables with by range / ranged key

Tags: join, powerquery, powerpivot

This is my first post, so please be gentle. My issue is that I need to join two tables based on a range. For simplicity we can use this example.

#### Table A:

Product Sales

*A 100 *B 200 *C 3000 *D 5000

#### Table B:

Sales_From Sales_To Category
*0 1000 Z
*10000 10000 N

#### Expected Result in Table A:

Product Sales Category
*A 100 Z
*B 200 Z
*C 3000 N
*D 5000 N

Actual example is more complex, so the solution should be straight-forward. Thank you!
Btw. how do I create a table [EDIT: In Stackoverflow questions]?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to create a table, not sure how useful this information would be

Assuming you have three columns in TableB with column headers of Column1,Column2,Column3 then ..

Add column .. index column

Add column ... custom column .. named Ending, formula =

```
={[Column2] .. try (#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Column2]-1) otherwise 99999}
```

Adjust the 99999 to be the maximum lookup value you want

This will create a range for each row from {Column 2 ... one less than Column 2 in next row}

click on arrows atop column Ending and expand into new rows

Use that column to merge the new TableB into TableA with a left outer join

sample code for TableB

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Ending", each {[Column2] .. try (#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Column2]-1) otherwise 99999}),
#"Expanded Ending" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Ending")
in #"Expanded Ending"
```

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else having the same issue in the future, this did the trick:

[power query merge two tables based on the transaction date between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62332654/power-query-merge-two-tables-based-on-the-transaction-date-between-two-dates)

However in the posted solution you need to cross both tables a and b completly at first, so if the data sets are >very< big this might not be the a smart one. Actually the no of rows you will get in step 1 is [NoOfRows_TableA]x[NoOfRows_TableB] which is a lot ...